# Правильная настройка Robots.txt

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Ссылки, которые я хочу закрыть, доступны по нескольким ссылкам.

```
/?page=feedback
```

и

```
/feedbak
```

достаточно ли в robots.txt указать что то одно? или нужно прописывать для каждой вариации url?

И будет ли такой "двойной" url считаться дублированным контентом со стороны поисковиков?

Answer (score 0):

Прописывать нужно обе вариации, т.к. идет четкое указание правила `Disalow: /?page=feedback`. Соответственно, это будет относится только к страницам, у которых есть в окончании указанный get-запрос

Правилом `Disalow: /feedback` мы перекрываем доступ как к странице `/feedback`, так и ко всему каталогу `/feedback/` в теории (Есть он у вас, или нет)